# Wine Tastings in Burgundy

Tags: france, burgundy

Planning a little trip through Europe which will put me for some time in Burgundy.

I am used to US wineries, which have a tasting room at the vineyard/winery and while you may not be able to visit the cellar without a prior invitation you can certainly come in for the tasting and purchase on site.

From the research I've done online I've only found one winery that offers on site wine tastings, which out of dozens in the area it seems odd.  I do understand that some of the Grand Cru producing wineries may only offer on site visits to distributors or critics but I don't think that they are the only ones producing.

So how would one arrange the tastings in Burgundy if not at the wineries? (Champagne and Alsace would be a plus.)

Comment: Certain vinyards do tours and purchasing on site but many are much smaller than US vineyards and don't have the staff (and wouldn't see the custom) to be permenantly open to visitors.

Comment: @CMaster I don't follow: *wouldn't see the custom*?  And noone said to be permanently open to visitors but certain days of the week with certain hours.

Comment: I'd gotten the impression from the inital question that you were used to being able to merely arrive at a vinyard for the tastings - I may have been wrong in that view. Burgundy isn't the most tourist-visited part of France mind. I've been told that the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guide_Hachette_des_Vins can be useful when planning where to visit.

Comment: @CMaster Most wineries do keep regular tasting room hours but not all although I haven't found any that didn't keep any hours at all (possibly by appointment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to organize it on your own, you'll have to rely on the winery goodwill to let you visit. If you intend to buy some wine, it will certainly ease the visit. I know a lot of Champagne can be visited.

Then you also have some formal tours around the wine theme that are organized. You can make a search for "oenotourisme" (this is the tourim related to wine).

Few links to assist you :

- http://www.vino-passion.co.uk/
- http://www.terredevins.com/thematique/oenotourisme/haltes-en-bourgogne/
- http://www.winetourisminfrance.com/an/
- http://www.champagne.fr/fr/decouvrir-la-champagne/tourisme/oenotourisme

Some of those links are in French but you can translate with Google Translator :)

Then, take also a look at the exhibitions agenda. In almost all regions, you will find every month an exhibition related to the wine theme where you can do some tastings.

Enjoy France!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of places to start your planning ....

http://www.burgundy-tourism.com/to-do-to-see/cellars?LabelsRecherche_40=De%20Vignes%20en%20Caves

http://www.cotedor-tourisme.com/bourgogne/route-des-grands-crus